# Python BeautifulSoup ошибка при парсинге

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Что не так с этим кодом?

```
 import requests as r
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


 counter = 0

 web = "https://bipbap.ru/krasivye-kartinki/kartinki-krasivyh-mashin-35-foto.html"

 boob = r.get(web).text
 sex = BeautifulSoup(boob, "lxml")
 boob1 = sex.findAll("span")
 for a in boob1:
      boob2 = a.find("img")
      print(boob2['src'])
```

[image: Вот сама ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция find может ничего не вернуть, то есть вернуть None. Предлагаю добавить блок try-except.

```
try:
    boob2 = a.find("img")
    print(boob2['src'])
except TypeError:
    pass
```